# While connecting MS SQL getting error "Data source name not found and no default driver specified QODBC3: Unable to connect"

Tags: qgis, sql-server

I have used the following code for connecting the Microsoft SQL Server's database. but at the time of opening database connection it is throwing an error.

Here is my code,

```
 from PyQt4.QtGui import * 
 from PyQt4.QtSql import * 
 from PyQt4.QtCore import * 
 import sys

 db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QODBC")
 db.setHostName("DB\DBCENTER2008R2");
 db.setDatabaseName("AU_Test");
 db.setUserName("sa");
 db.setPassword("sa12");
 if (db.open()==False):
     QMessageBox.critical(None, "Database Error",db.lastError().text())
```